# Deleting user from sudoer

Tags: linux

I would like to know the command to remove a user from the sudoer list in Linux. I have added the user using this command:

```
sudo adduser user_name
```

and also added it to a group.

I now want to remove the user from the sudoer list. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not as straight forward as running a command.  There is no sudoerlist - the sudoers file is a list of instructions which can provide users - or groups various permissions.  You can edit this file using visudo if you are good with vi.  If not, you arguably should not be messing with it, but can probably use nano /etc/sudoers (as root).  The sudoers file is usually quite well documented.

Depending on your OS though, you may not actually need to do this.  Most distros have a group, and elevated permissions are granted by simply modifying who has access to what group.   You may want to look through the sudoers file to see what group/groups there are - In my ubuntu 16.04 there is an "admin" group and a "sudo" group. "wheel" and "admin" groups are other common ones.

As the user is probably already a member of a group with sudo access, typing (as root) grep "username" /etc/group" will show a list of groups the user is a member of.  To remove the user you can (as root) edit them out of /etc/group or use a command like

```
gpasswd -d username groupname
```

or

```
deluser username groupname
```

Comment: Shouldn’t it be **gpasswd**?

Comment: Thanks a  lot it works fine :) first command - gpasswd -d username groupname

Answer (score 1):

That command doesn't add the user to the `/etc/sudoers` file.

Depending on what group(s) you added the user to, that might grant them access to use sudo.  Check group membership for the user with `groups username`.

You edit the `/etc/sudoers` file using the `visudo` utility - if you don't like vi/vim you can use any other editor by specifying it as an environment variable.

```
sudo EDITOR=/bin/nano visudo
```

Note that while the file is plain text, it is important to use `visudo` to edit it because `visudo` will check the syntax, etc. before actually saving it.  With bad syntax, you wouldn't be able to run `sudo` again to fix it.

So... check group members for your user, check what groups are allowed `sudo` access, and check what users are allowed `sudo` access.

Contents of a basic `/etc/sudoers` as distributed by Debian/Ubuntu/etc

```
ivan@darkstar:~$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: Thanks, but we can delete the user?

Comment: @user983675 - sure.  `deluser username` or `userdel username` with some options.  Check `man` pages for each, decide which is appropriate.  Might want to do some reading on managing users and groups on a *nix system - https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/linux-users-and-groups/